# how do I get blender to stop rounding up my dimensions?

Tags: units, dimensions

I'm using 2.8 and If I have an object that is say 10.75 on the z axis the read out will change to 10.8 once I've hit enter. It doesn't change the dimension to 10.8 and if I click on the box again it shows me that it's 10.75. It mostly just annoys me and makes me constantly click the box just to double check that my dimensions are correct and I haven't made a mistake.

[image: Here is the image showing the rounded dimension]
[image: here is the image showing the actual dimension when I click on the box]

Comment: Can you please provide some screenshot with rounded dimensions? Blender rounds the dimensions to three decimal places.

Comment: Okay I added screenshots. Yes I'm used to Blender rounding to 3 decimal places but this started happening recently.

Answer (score 1):

By default blender uses metric measurement system with Unit System set to None and rounding to 3 decimal places wich best suited for real world objects:

[image: Unit System None]

If you using Impereal Unit System rounding wich default to Feet rounding can be from 0 to 3 decimal places. This can be inconvenient when manipulating with a gizmo.

[image: Unit System Impereal]

In this case, you can use Length in Thou wich meant "Thousandth of an inch":

[image: Unit System Impereal Length in Thou]

For more complex cases: work with micro or macro objects - suitable overriding of Unit Scale:

[image: Unit Scale overriding]

Comment: Is there somewhere that I can set the number of digits that the dimensions gets rounded to?

Comment: No. But you can change Unit Scale to get almost like that result.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just activating *Separate Units* solved the problem.

[image: Rounding]

[image: Fixed]